# Pinch zooming on an image in Xamarin

Tags: android, image, xamarin, pinchzoom, android-bitmap

In `Xamarin`, what is the best way to enable pinch zooming for an image? Currently I have just an `ImageView` that has a `Bitmap` image as an image.

I have done some research, and I have found a few examples where people have used some other libraries but would like some advice on the best way to enable pinch zooming on an image before I start writing this code.

So, what is the best way to enable pinch zooming on an image in `Android`, specifically `Xamarin`?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 12):

You can get ImageView zoom-in capabilities and panning of the zoomed in image by using the Monodroidtoolkit ScaleImageView.

First, add the ScaleImageView.cs class to your project using [the code from here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MonoDroidToolkit/blob/7d2f3a9a819aa9cfe17d58abd07908a647ac5467/src/XamarinAndroidToolkit/Toolkit/ScaleImageView.cs).

The toolkit also has a sample of how to use it, basically you add an [activity](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MonoDroidToolkit/blob/master/src/Samples/ScaleImageActivity.cs) like this:

```
namespace Samples
{
    [Activity(Label = "My Activity")]
    public class ScaleImageActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ScaleImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, add the [ScaleImage.axml](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MonoDroidToolkit/blob/master/src/Samples/Resources/Layout/ScaleImage.axml) layout by creating a layout with the following XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<com.refractored.monodroidtoolkit.ScaleImageView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:src="@drawable/seattle"
  android:id="@+id/AnimateImage">
</com.refractored.monodroidtoolkit.ScaleImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, in this sample it is loading an image of Seattle from the drawable folder, so add the seattle.jpg image which can be found [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MonoDroidToolkit/blob/master/src/Samples/Resources/Drawable/seattle.jpg)

The MonoDroidToolkit has a project with a bunch of samples including this one